# Show that $\lvert \lvert (x,y) \rvert \rvert \rightarrow \infty$ implies $f(x,y) = x^2-4xy+4y^2+y^4-2y^3+y^2 \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the function
>   $$f(x,y) = x^2-4xy+5y^2+y^4-2y^3.$$
>
> Show that $$\lvert \lvert (x,y) \rvert \rvert \rightarrow \infty \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(x,y) \rightarrow+\infty.$$

I do not see how I could prove this in a "nice way". Is there any way to avoid a lot of case distinctions, so to avoid considering each case like

$$x \rightarrow +\infty, y \rightarrow -\infty $$
$$x \rightarrow -\infty, y \rightarrow -\infty $$

and so on separately?

Comment: Check your typing. You have two terms for $y^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that I can simplify this, I will make an edit.

Comment: HINT: $y^4$ is of highest degree

Comment: @SaketGurjar That may or may not help, but it doesn't solve the problem _per se_, because $||(x,y)||\to\infty$ does not imply $|y|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$f(x,y) = x^2-4xy+4y^2+y^4-2y^3+y^2=(x-2y)^2+y^2(y-1)^2$$

If $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm, then $||(x,y)||^2=x^2+y^2$ and easily we can see that $$f(x,y)=||(x-2y,y-y^2)||^2=||(x,y)-(2y,y^2)||^2\geq(||(x,y)||-||(2y,y^2)||)^2$$ (by a variant of triangle inequality).